# Is this Spring bean stateless?

Tags: spring

Is the below bean stateless and therefore thread-safe? More specifically my consern are the injected values the String array. Does this interfere with the state of the bean? NO right?

```
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ServiceImpl.class);

/* Injected values properties file. */
private String[] values;

@Autowired
private DAO dao;


@Transactional
@Override
public void invoke(String submissionId) {

    dosomething....
}
}
```

Comment: what kind of value is assigned to `values` array

Answer (score 3):

The main question to ask here is

> What is a stateless object ?

The answer is that your Object is stateless if its properties does not change during its lifetime. I assume your bean is scoped as a `singleton` and therefore, as long as the `values` property does not change during the lifetime of your bean it is stateless. Otherwise not.

Comment: The bean is singleton yes. I just read these values. no changing.

Comment: Then it is stateless as I said above.

Answer (score 0):

It is stateless, if there is no write access to the `values` array. Otherwise, you will probably run into errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not modify the properties (or the properties of the objects refered by your bean) after initialization, the bean is effective stateless. No matter what kind of type you use.

So if you do not modfiy the array or one of its items, you bean is effective stateless/ effective immutable.